# Getting Error to add the TtmCdEnvironment id in SDL Web8.1.1

Tags: web8, topology-manager

Getting Below Error while running following command i try to add TtmCdEnvironment id in SDL Web 8.1.1 discovery service is up and running  [link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8)

```
Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id SampleCD -EnvironmentPurpose Staging -DiscoveryEndpointUrl http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc -AuthenticationType OAuth -ClientId cmuser -ClientSecret CMUserP@ssw0rd
```

> Add-TtmCdEnvironment : Unable to save item of type 'CdEnvironmentData' with id 'Staging'.
>   One or more errors occurred.
>   An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc' in CD Environment 'Staging'. 
>   One or more errors occurred.
>   The TokenServiceCapability is not configured in the Content Discovery Service http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id Staging -EnvironmentPurpose Staging -DiscoveryEndpointU ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:AddCdEnvironmentCommand) [Add-TtmCdEnvironment], DataS 
>      erviceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdEnvironmentCommand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use OAuth authentication on your Discovery service, you firstly need to register `TokenServiceCapability` there. It can be done using `discovery-registration.jar` tool described here: [link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-479E441E-744D-44BB-B326-E3F48F4362B5) or [link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-12D1D919-2D08-40C3-91A0-B6C0A643C29F)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response issue got resolved after executing **java -jar discovery-registration.jar update**