# Error adding CD environment in Topology Manager - TokenServiceCapability

Tags: web8, topology-manager

Following the instructions [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8) to setup SDL Web 8.5 on a single server but when I run the **Add-TtmCdEnvironment** command I get the following:

```
Add-TtmCdEnvironment : Unable to save item of type 'CdEnvironmentData' with id 'SampleCD
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://localhost:8082/d
Environment 'SampleCD'.
One or more errors occurred.
The TokenServiceCapability is not configured in the Content Discovery Service http://loc
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id SampleCD -EnvironmentPurpose "Staging" -Disc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:AddCdEnvi
   ronment], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdEnvironmentCommand
```

I found [another answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14428/error-with-discovery-service-and-discovery-registration-jar) but as a quick test I enabled DEBUG log level to see if anything appeared in the logs.

In my cd_odata log I see this:

```
2017-03-02 15:39:18,736 INFO  AkkaConfiguration - Creating actor system
2017-03-02 15:39:25,378 DEBUG ODataEdmRegistryImpl - registerClasses: classes=[class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ConfigurationItem, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ConfigurationValue, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.Environment, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.PreviewWebServiceCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContentServiceCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.DestinationURL, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.DeployerCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.WebCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.AudienceManagerCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.AudienceManagerSynchronizationCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.SmartTargetManagementCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.SmartTargetQueryCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContextServiceCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContextualImageDeliveryCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.UGCCommunityServiceCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.UGCModerationServiceCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.WebApplication, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.PublicationMapping, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.BaseURL, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.KeyValuePair, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.AudienceManagerSynchronizationTarget, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.AudienceManagerTarget, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.UGCCommunityServiceTarget, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.UGCModerationServiceTarget, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.functions.GetExtensionPropertyForHostFunction, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.functions.GetBuildVersionFunction, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.functions.GetBuildVersionFunctionImport, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.actions.SetExtensionProperty, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.actions.ResetServiceAction, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.actions.ResetServiceActionImport, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.TokenServiceCapability, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContentKeyValuePair, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.DeployerKeyValuePair, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.PreviewWebKeyValuePair, class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.WebKeyValuePair]
2017-03-02 15:39:27,155 INFO  ODataServiceConfiguration - Initializing OData service routing
2017-03-02 15:40:06,437 DEBUG ODataServiceImpl - Handling request: GET http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/TokenServiceCapabilities?$top=1
2017-03-02 15:40:06,484 INFO  ODataEdmRegistryImpl - Building EntityDataModel
2017-03-02 15:40:06,530 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: ConfigurationItems for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Configuration.ConfigurationItem
2017-03-02 15:40:06,530 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: ConfigurationValues for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Configuration.ConfigurationValue
2017-03-02 15:40:06,530 DEBUG AnnotationSingletonFactory - Creating Singleton named: Environment for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.Environment
2017-03-02 15:40:06,546 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: PreviewWebServiceCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.PreviewWebServiceCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,546 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: ContentServiceCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.ContentServiceCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,546 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: DeployerCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.DeployerCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,546 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: WebCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.WebCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: AudienceManagerCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.AudienceManagerCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: AudienceManagerSynchronizationCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.AudienceManagerSynchronizationCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: SmartTargetManagementCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.SmartTargetManagementCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: SmartTargetQueryCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.SmartTargetQueryCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: ContextServiceCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.ContextServiceCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: ContextualImageDeliveryCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.ContextualImageDeliveryCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: UGCCommunityServiceCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.UGCCommunityServiceCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: UGCModerationServiceCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.UGCModerationServiceCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: WebApplications for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.WebApplication
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: PublicationMappings for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.PublicationMapping
2017-03-02 15:40:06,562 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: AudienceManagerSynchronizationTargets for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.AudienceManagerSynchronizationTarget
2017-03-02 15:40:06,577 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: AudienceManagerTargets for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.AudienceManagerTarget
2017-03-02 15:40:06,577 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: UGCCommunityServiceTargets for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.UGCCommunityServiceTarget
2017-03-02 15:40:06,577 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: UGCModerationServiceTargets for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.UGCModerationServiceTarget
2017-03-02 15:40:06,577 DEBUG AnnotationEntitySetFactory - Creating EntitySet named: TokenServiceCapabilities for entity type: Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.TokenServiceCapability
2017-03-02 15:40:06,655 DEBUG ODataParserImpl - Parsing URI: http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/TokenServiceCapabilities?$top=1
2017-03-02 15:40:06,812 DEBUG ODataParserImpl - Parse result: ODataUri(http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc,ResourcePathUri(EntitySetPath(TokenServiceCapabilities,None),List(TopOption(1))))
2017-03-02 15:40:07,280 DEBUG AbstractRenderer - Target type is Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.TokenServiceCapability and is it collection true
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG AtomRenderer - Renderer score is 31
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG AbstractRenderer - Target type is Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.TokenServiceCapability and is it collection true
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG AbstractJsonRenderer - Renderer score is 100
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG JsonRenderer - Renderer score is 100
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG JsonServiceDocumentRenderer - Score of JSON service document renderer is 0
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG AbstractRenderer - Target type is Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.TokenServiceCapability and is it collection true
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG PrimitiveRenderer - Renderer score is 0
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG XMLServiceDocumentRenderer - Score of XML service document renderer is 0
2017-03-02 15:40:07,296 DEBUG AbstractRenderer - Target type is Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.TokenServiceCapability and is it collection true
2017-03-02 15:40:07,312 DEBUG JsonRenderer - Start rendering entity(es) for request: GET http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/TokenServiceCapabilities?$top=1
2017-03-02 15:40:07,327 DEBUG JsonRenderer - End rendering entity(es) for request: GET http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/TokenServiceCapabilities?$top=1
2017-03-02 15:40:07,343 DEBUG ODataServiceImpl - Request completed in 906
```

Which suggests to me my Token Service is running OK?

I stuck http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/TokenServiceCapabilities?$top=1 in a browser and got:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><feed xmlns:metadata="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata" xmlns:data="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" metadata:context="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/$metadata#TokenServiceCapabilities" xml:base="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc">
<id>http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/TokenServiceCapabilities</id>
<title></title>
<updated>2017-03-02T15:47:36.883Z</updated>
<link rel="self" title="TokenServiceCapabilities" href="TokenServiceCapabilities"></link>
</feed>
```

Yet I still cant add my CD environment in Topology Manager.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 3):

Appears you need to register the TokenServiceCapability capability in the Discovery service. This [answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14461/getting-error-to-add-the-ttmcdenvironment-id-in-sdl-web8-1-1?rq=1) helped.